# Backing up an OpenStack Swift Object Store

Tags: cloud, backup, openstack, openstack-swift

We're using OpenStack's Swift Object Store to store user data. I appreciate that our Cloud provider has their own backup/redundancy system in place, but we want to implement our own backup system that stores a copy of everything offsite – somewhere like Amazon Glacier. (Visions of Code Space's data loss loom large in our minds.)

I can't seem to find any information anywhere on how to replicate/backup an OpenStack object store. Is there a best-practices way of doing this? The best we've come up with is writing our own backup process that walks through the store and manually transfers everything offsite, but that seems fairly inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid data loss by replication in swift. In swift data is stored in `storage nodes`. You can increase number of storage nodes to prevent data loss.

```
￼cd /etc/swift
swift-ring-builder account.builder create 18 no_of_replica 1 
swift-ring-builder container.builder create 18 no_of_replica 1 
swift-ring-builder object.builder create 18 no_of_replica 1
```

You can set no_of_replica as you wish, but you should configure that much machines as swift storage nodes.